# How to add alert on cross button click of browser window using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, browser, alert

I am using this currently it is showing an alert but when the user clicks on the leave, and cancel buttons how to take control of it? how to change the text of the alert. It is currently not working.

```
 window.addEventListener('unload',
e.returnValue = "Are you sure?";
)

 window.addEventListener('beforeunload',
e.returnValue = "Are you sure?";
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to show an alert when the user attempts to close the tab. If so, you should try the event `beforeunload`. Keep in mind that this comes with a bunch of drawbacks and doesn't always work on mobile users, for example.
You can find more details about the `beforeunload` event on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: I know that event i have tried. but my question is ut shows alert with the options leave, cancel. How to add functionality on that leave button